# jQuery combox value change hide button

Tags: jquery, combobox

I want to emulate the following scenario:

- if  `combox` is equal to `0` hide the button
- else if `combox` is equal to `1,2,3...` show the button

I have tried the following:

```
$('#Variant1').val().change(function(){
  if (val === 0) {
    $('#startbtn').hide();
  } else {
    $('#startbtn').show();
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Variant1').on('change', function() {
  if( this.value == 0){

        $('#startbtn').hide();

    }  else {

        $('#startbtn').show();
    } 
})


<select id="Variant1">
    <option value="0">Zero</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
```